# How to return multiple match results and output them to a cell as concatenated text?

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, array

Suppose I have the following data:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val1 | Str1 |  |  |
| 2 | ValM | Str2 |  |  |
| 3 | val2 | Str3 |  |  |
| 4 | ValM | Str4 |  |  |
| 5 | ValM | Str5 |  |  |
| 6 | val3 | Str6 |  |  |
| 7 | ValM | Str7 |  |  |
| 8 | val4 | Str8 |  |  |
| 9 | val5 | Str9 |  |  |
| 10 | ValM | Str10 |  |  |

I would like to:

1. find all matches of `ValM` present in column A
2. for each found value at step 1, get the corresponding row value present in column B
3. populate a cell, say D1, with text concated from step 2

That is, I would like this output:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val1 | Str1 |  | Str2, Str4, Str5, Str7, Str10 |
| 2 | ValM | Str2 |  |  |
| 3 | val2 | Str3 |  |  |
| 4 | ValM | Str4 |  |  |
| 5 | ValM | Str5 |  |  |
| 6 | val3 | Str6 |  |  |
| 7 | ValM | Str7 |  |  |
| 8 | val4 | Str8 |  |  |
| 9 | val5 | Str9 |  |  |
| 10 | ValM | Str10 |  |  |

Is it possible to make that with LibreOffice Calc (without using macros)? If so, how?

Note: I tried to use Array Functions with INDEX, MATCH and TEXTJOIN without success.

**Update**

And how to manage to output a list-like content (instead of a comma separated list) in the cell D1?

D1 cell list-like content:

```
- Str2
- Str4
- Str5
- Str7
- Str10
```

Comment: I found a possible solution here: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=94231#p448753

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type the following formula on the formula bar:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE(), IF(A1:A10="valm",B1:B10,""))
```

When done typing, with your cursor still in the formula bar, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Curly braces will envelop the formula as seen on the image below.

[image: Result]

Regarding the update part of the question, you need the change the formula a little bit. The delimiter will be a new line using the `CHAR` function, and concatenating the text/string `-`  to the output range. The formula will change to:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE(), IF(A1:A10="valm","- " & B1:B10,""))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the formula as mentioned before

[image: Result of update question]

Comment: Thanks @Reddy. I just updated the question with one more challenge

Comment: @Backo See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excel version of that. I didn't used filter function here, so you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> for array calculation. If libreoffice use a seperate function for array calculations (like G Sheet `ArrayFormula`), you might need to use that.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(INDEX(C1:C10, FIND("ValM", B1:B10)*ROW(B1:B10)), ""))
```

Here I have it for G-Sheets

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(FIND("ValM", B1:B10)*ROW(B1:B10), ""), A1:C10, 3), "")))
```

Comment: I tried to "convert" it to LibreOffice without success :(

Comment: Yeah that was wierd - I tried it on G-Sheets with some modifications and here's how it looks like:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zQ0cwXyC93OcEfdTP-vnv2q-eH6yoJYNxPfMTJBo7kg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The linked doc requires access permission. Please, make it openly accessible.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zQ0cwXyC93OcEfdTP-vnv2q-eH6yoJYNxPfMTJBo7kg/edit?usp=sharing